# Stay on shop page when add to cart

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using elementor pro, woocommerce, ocean wp theme and the elementor custom skin add-on.

I want to build an ecommerce website without products pages but only a shop page, in order to have all my products on the shop page with add to cart button and a quantity selector. 
For that, I used the loop system and it works quite well.

I only have 1 issue : when you add a product to the cart, it automaticaly redirects you to the product page.

I don't want to use the products pages. I would like to disable them.
I want customers to stay on the shop page for further shopping. Only access to cart page or checkout page when they click on the add to cart menu.

If it's possible to do that without coding it's best, otherwise, please tell me how to do if you can :)

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed if you click on the tick mark named as " Redirect to the cart page after successful addition". You will find it in Woocommerce > Settings > General.
This will help customers to go to the cart page after they add something to the cart. **But I don't know how to redirect customers to the shop page after they add to cart something. I am also asking for that help.**

See the screenshot:
[image]